# How to fix "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found."?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, scipy, anaconda3

After installing a fresh copy of Anaconda 3 for my windows 10 and running my code, I am receiving this error message and I am not sure why "scipy" modules are not imported correctly.
I need help to figure this out.

$ D:/Users/username/Anaconda3/python.exe d:/Users/username/Desktop/sol-tl/sol_357.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Users\username\Desktop\some_name\my_script.py", line 37, in <module>
    from fluorescence.calculator import (electron_plotter, enter_computation_scheme, total_plotter)
  File "d:\Users\username\Desktop\sol-tl\fluorescence\calculator.py", line 18, in <module>
    from fluorescence.imports_module import (np, List, Tuple, Path, perf_counter, ode, odeint,
  File "d:\Users\username\Desktop\sol-tl\fluorescence\imports_module.py", line 25, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
  File "D:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 400, in <module>
    from .optimize import *
  File "D:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 36, in <module>
    from ._numdiff import approx_derivative
  File "D:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_numdiff.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
  File "D:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from .eigen import *
  File "D:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "D:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .arpack import *
  File "D:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _arpack
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that the new release of `Anaconda` (3.9.12) is having issues with “Scipy” package, I removed the package from `Conda` and re-installed it using `pip`. Now, the code runs happily.